# How to split GO Gorilla Mux routes in 2 separate files of the same package

Tags: go, routes, gorilla, mux

I have separate file routes.go (package routes) where I store all my routes and handlers.
But I want to split this file in 2 files. I want to rename my routes.go to main.go and create new additional file moduleX.go (package routes).
How can I do that?
I want to store all my routes in multiple files of the same "package routes".

```html
package routes

import (
 "github.com/gorilla/mux"
 "net/http"
 "github.com/---/001/models"
 "github.com/---/001/sessions"
 "github.com/---/001/utils"
 "github.com/---/001/middleware"
)

func NewRouter() *mux.Router {
 r := mux.NewRouter()
 r.HandleFunc("/", middleware.AuthRequired(indexGetHandler)).Methods("GET")
 r.HandleFunc("/", middleware.AuthRequired(indexPostHandler)).Methods("POST")
 r.HandleFunc("/signup", signupGetHandler).Methods("GET")
 r.HandleFunc("/signup", signupPostHandler).Methods("POST")
 r.HandleFunc("/signin", signinGetHandler).Methods("GET")
 r.HandleFunc("/signin", signinPostHandler).Methods("POST")
 r.HandleFunc("/signout", signoutGetHandler).Methods("GET")
 r.HandleFunc("/services", middleware.AuthRequired(servicesHandler)).Methods("GET")
 fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))
 r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
 return r
}
```

I want move all "/signup" and "/signin" routes and handlers outside of this main file. And then somehow to pass them back to this NewRouter function.
You can provide me just a book or some online example.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use another function that modifies the router to do that.

```
//In another file
func addSignHandler(r *mux.Router) {
    r.HandleFunc("/signup", signupGetHandler).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/signup", signupPostHandler).Methods("POST")
    r.HandleFunc("/signin", signinGetHandler).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/signin", signinPostHandler).Methods("POST")
    r.HandleFunc("/signout", signoutGetHandler).Methods("GET")
}
```

And to use it:

```
func NewRouter() *mux.Router {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", middleware.AuthRequired(indexGetHandler)).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/", middleware.AuthRequired(indexPostHandler)).Methods("POST")

    addSignHandler(r)

    r.HandleFunc("/services", middleware.AuthRequired(servicesHandler)).Methods("GET")
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))
    r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
    return r
}
```

Or even better, you can refactor your code to make it more consistent:

```
func addMainHandler(r *mux.Router) {
    r.HandleFunc("/", middleware.AuthRequired(indexGetHandler)).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/", middleware.AuthRequired(indexPostHandler)).Methods("POST")
    r.HandleFunc("/services", middleware.AuthRequired(servicesHandler)).Methods("GET")
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))
    r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
}
```

And simplify the `NewRouter` to:

```
func NewRouter() *mux.Router {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    addMainHandler(r)
    addSignHandler(r)
    return r
}
```

Comment: Yaay!! Thank You! I was really close to this solution! Thank You so much. Unfortunately i cant up-vote this answer.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for taking the time to respond.